# Increase number of replicas automatically

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am running a service in Docker Swarm on a single machine. This is what I did to deploy the service:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml MyApplication
```

Content of **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: myimage:1.0
        ports:
            - "9000:80"
            - "9001:443"
        deploy:
            replicas: 3
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: "0.5"
                    memory: 256M
                restart_policy:
                    condition: on-failure
```

Is Docker Swarm able to increase number of replicas automatically based on current traffic? If yes, how to configure it to do so? If no, how can I achieve it, maybe use Kubernetes?

Comment: I have not found this functionality. And implement it by my self.

Comment: How did you implement it by yourself?

Comment: By monitor traffic and send update service command to API: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ServiceUpdate

Comment: What do you use to monitor traffic?

Comment: With Kubernetes you can achieve it with [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling using Custom Metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics)

Comment: I have the number of custom metrics. I do not think it will be relevant for you. What you understand as traffic?

Comment: You can try to look into https://github.com/sahajsoft/docker-swarm-service-autoscaler or build solution with your team :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on CPU utilization of Pods it is possible to autoscale Deployments. You need to use `kubectl autoscale` command, which creates a HorizontalPodAutoscaler object that targets a specified resource and scales it as needed. The HPA periodically adjusts the number of replicas of the scale target to match the average CPU utilization that you specify.

When using `kubectl autoscale`, you need to specify a maximum and minimum number of replicas for your application, as well as a CPU utilization target.

Take a look for the example: to set the maximum number of replicas to five and the minimum to two, with a CPU utilization target of 60% utilization, run the following command:

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment my-app --max 5 --min 2 --cpu-percent 60
```

Please, found more about it in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale) and in the [following article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-kubernetes-for-autoscaling). I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Also, the metrics-server pods should be deployed on the cluster. Else, when you run kubectl hpa command, the cpu target value will be unknown.  The pods will not be auto scaled.